# Strange NSNumberFormatter crash

Tags: objective-c, nsnumberformatter, invalid-argument

The code is simple:

```
static NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = nil;

if (numberFormatter == nil) {
    numberFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
}
```

However, it crashes on the last line:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSDateFormatter setNumberStyle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5c378d0'
```

How is it possible?

Comment: If I could downvote my own question, I would.

Comment: There are much worse questions on SO. Otherwise I'd downvote it for you ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you created an NSDateFormatter, not an NSNumberFormatter.

Comment: Oh my god, I've seen this moment after I posted that to stackoverflow, but sadly I can't delete the post.

Comment: @golergka: Everyone makes obvious mistakes sometimes. I couldn't count how many times I've said "just a stupid typo".

Comment: nevertheless, it's embarrassing to post such a question in public.